# Add and subtract 3 month from a given date time

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, momentjs, utc

I have this start date : `2023-09-03T00:00:00+05:30`
and end date : `2023-09-10T00:00:00+05:30`

I want to subtract 90 days from start date and add 90 days from end date

and then convert it to UTC format

for that I was using this function in angular

```
moment(startStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
moment(endStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

How can I do that?

Comment: While there might be a setDays function in moment, the fact is that dates on computers are represented as the number of milliseconds past Jan,1 1980 12AM GMT (As I remember) but regardless of what the start date is, all you need to do is convert your moment dates to the number of milliseconds, add and subtract 3 months worth of milliseconds, and convert back.

Comment: Note that the MomentJS project is considered a legacy project; See [Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for more.

Comment: @ControlAltDel—different environments and operating systems use different epochs. ECMAScript uses 1 Jan 1970, as do most UNIX operating systems and MacOS X. Classic Mac OS used 1 Jan 1904, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moment you can use `add` and `substract` functions. Example below:

```
var startDate = moment(startStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
var endDate = moment(endStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

startDate =  startDate.subtract(90, 'days');
console.log(startDate);
endDate =  endDate.add(90, 'days');
console.log(endDate);

// then do your utc conversion
```

Reference material:

[moment add function link](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/)

[moment subsctract function link](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/02-subtract/)